# How to redirect in sails after login with sails-permissions

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-permissions

I've just started using sails and am trying to implement authentication. I installed everything like adviced, then created a simple login form with jade:

```
form(action="/auth/local", method="post")
     div
        input(name="identifier" type="text")
     div
        input(name="password" type="password")
     div
        input(type="submit")
```

This logs `authentication successful` and forwards me to the page, returning

```
{
  "createdBy": 1,
  "owner": 1,
  "username": "admin",
  "email": "admin@example.com",
  "id": 1,
  "createdAt": "2015-09-25T18:14:20.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2015-09-25T18:39:30.000Z",
  "gravatarUrl": "https://gravatar.com/avatar/e64c7d89f26bd1972efa854d13d7dd61"
}
```

Now I want to redirect the newly logged in user to any page, so I tried to change the form's action to

```
/auth/local/login
```

which redirects to /login, but logs

```
warn: Error: Invalid action
```

serverside.

In my config/routes file I have a route like this:

```
"/login" : {
    view:"login"
}
```

What is the correct way to setup redirection in sails after login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `/auth/local/login`, it tries to call `login` action for passport local strategy. But as you can see from [source](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth/blob/01817ab26a1bf9d647a04f5db6f8f649dc94adaa/api/services/passport.js#L214-L227) local strategy have three actions:

`register`: This method creates a new user from a specified email, username and password and assign the newly created user a local Passport.

`connect` : This function can be used to assign a local Passport to a user who doens't  have one already. This would be the case if the user registered using a third-party service and therefore never set a password.

`disconnect`: Disconnect a passport from a user

For other actions it'll throw `Invalid action` error.

The right way to redirect after successful login is to **use [`next` query parameter](https://github.com/dbkaplun/sails-auth/blob/b4e82900e3489dda503e03dae6f4af3da4850bd2/api/controllers/AuthController.js#L125-L127)**:

```
/auth/local?next=login
```